# Which function grows faster: N Log N or N^(1+ε/√(log N))

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, asymptotics, runtime-analysis, big-o-notation

How would you go about solving this problem?

[image]

I thought about using a limit infinity approach, but got confused and Wolfram Alpha didn't provide any explanation. 
[image]

Comment: Seems that the result from Wolfram Alpha tells you everything you need to know to answer the question.  It's hard to tell what kind of answer you are looking for, but if you are confused about how to use limits, see https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/824/sorting-functions-by-asymptotic-growth for an explanation.

Comment: @D.W. I think the question is _how to evaluate this limit_. The first two approaches I tried to evaluate it didn't work! I had an answer ready to post, but you closed the question before I could post it.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable question.  Want to edit the question to make it clearer what's being asked?  Then we can re-open it for answering.

Comment: OK. @buddybuddybuddybuddy, please edit the question to clarify whether this was the intended meaning. If it was, ping me afterwards with an @ comment and I'll come back and post my answer.